# Predicting Clothing Size Ratios when different products have different size methodologies

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling

- For context, when a retailer buys in a clothing item they have to stock it in various sizes. The ratio of stock for each size is referred to as the "size ratio" of the product. E.g. S=0.2, M=0.5, L=0.3
- I am looking to build a model that predicts the size curve ratio of sales at the end of the season based on data available at the start of the season e.g. historic sales data, product attributes.
- The data is structured so that on each line I have a product, product size, and the actual size ratio that sales accounted for in that size.
- The issue is that the data uses different size methodology depending on the product e.g. jeans might be in numerical sizes, but tops might be in S,M,L etc.  So essentially the model is predicting the size ratio for each line.
- I was thinking that I could take each product, look at the range of sizes, count them, then align them in the centre?  For example, product 1 has sizes S,M, L and product 2 has sizes 1,2,3,4,5.  I could align the M and 3.  However, I am unsure of how to get this to work.

**Questions: How can I standardise the sizes?**

Comment: One can use tables to map individual sizes to e.g. US letter sizes (L,M etc.), but of course only the when the planned application of the prediction result allows this. See e.g. here https://www.hm.com/il/sizeguide/sizeguide_ladies

Answer (score 2):

You start out with a size ratio $r\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where the "source" product has $n$ different sizes, and the ratios sum to one, $\sum_{i=1}^nr_n=1$. The goal is to map this to a different dimensionality, $s=f(r)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ so that the target ratio again adds up to one, $\sum_{j=1}^ms_j=1$, and the mapping does not shift around mass "too much". (For instance, if $n=m$, then $f$ should be the identity mapping.)

The simplest mapping would be a linear one, using a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$,

$$ f\colon r\mapsto s := M r.$$

Let $m_{ij}$ denote the entry of $M$ in the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column. The following will work:

$$ m_{ij} := n\times \max\bigg\{0,\min\Big\{\frac{j}{n},\frac{i}{m}\Big\}-\max\Big\{\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{i-1}{m}\Big\}\bigg\}. $$

This works for $n<m$ and $n>m$ and gives the identity matrix for $n=m$. A few examples:

- $n=3, m=4$:

\begin{pmatrix}{}
  0.75 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.25 & 0.50 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.50 & 0.25 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 0.75 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

- $n=4, m=4$:

\begin{pmatrix}{}
  1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

- $n=5, m=4$:

\begin{pmatrix}{}
  1.00 & 0.67 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.33 & 1.00 & 0.33 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.67 & 1.00 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

As an example, here is how a size ratio of length $n=10$ would be mapped to $m=7$:

[image: sizes]

Of course, this only works if you have an [ordinally scaled attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data), like a *single* size. It won't work with pants or bras that have *two* different size attributes, nor with colors that have no natural ordering.

R code:

```
make_scale_matrix <- function( nsource, ndest ) {
    MM <- matrix(NA, ncol=nsource, nrow=ndest)
    for ( row in 1:ndest ) {
        for ( col in 1:nsource ) {
            MM[row,col] <- nsource *
              max(0, min(col/nsource,row/ndest)-max((col-1)/nsource,(row-1)/ndest))
        }
    }  
    MM
}

prettyprint <- function(MM) {
    # https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55424/22201
    MM_xtable <- xtable(MM,align=rep("",ncol(MM)+1)) 
    print(MM_xtable,tabular.environment="pmatrix", hline.after=NULL, 
      include.rownames=FALSE, include.colnames=FALSE)
}

prettyprint(make_scale_matrix(3,4))
prettyprint(make_scale_matrix(4,4))
prettyprint(make_scale_matrix(5,3))

set.seed(1)
foo <- runif(10)
source_ratio <- foo/sum(foo)
target_ratio <- (make_scale_matrix(length(source_ratio),7)%*%source_ratio)[,1]
ylim <- c(0,max(c(source_ratio,target_ratio)))

opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,1))
    plot(source_ratio,type="o",main="Source",pch=19,ylim=ylim,xlab="Size",ylab="")
    plot(target_ratio,type="o",main="Target",pch=19,ylim=ylim,xlab="Size",ylab="")
par(opar)
```

Comment: (+1) Question: One can define a "natural" ordering on jeans, e.g. first sort by waist, then by length. Can we say it is ordinally scaled in this case ?

Comment: That would be possible, yes. I don't know how meaningful the results would be, though... If both waists and lengths go from 28 to 42, then this would essentially say that W28/L42 is as similar to W28/L40 as to W30/L28, since the transformation above silently assumes interval scaled data.