# Condense a time series into a given number of points

Tags: time-series

What is the term for condensing a time series consisting of an arbitrary number of points (X), into one consisting of K points? Google searches for "condensing" or "reducing array" weren't fruitful, so I'm probably using the wrong term.

```
[1, 3, 7, 9] -> [2, 8]  // X=4, K=2
```

Also, how should this be done for non-trivial cases, e.g. when X is not a multiple of K (condensing 150 points into 100 points) or when there are gaps in the timeline?

Comment: What do you mean by "condensing"?

Comment: @Tim: that's pretty much the problem :) I thought the example would help... in the meantime I found out that "downsampling" might describe what I'm looking for, though none of the [three common methods I've seen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downsample) produces the intended result from my example (simply averaging by X/K buckets).

Comment: Based on Gascoyne's clarifications of his original question, I have deleted my answer as not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a canonical term, but [there are hits for "time series compression"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=time+series+compression&t=ffsb&ia=web).

I give a simple approach to compressing (or uncompressing/"smearing out") in nontrivial cases [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/355738/1352), though it won't work if there are gaps in the data.